# convert markdown to pdf in commandline

Tags: command-line, pdf, markdown, pandoc

what is the simplest tool to convert markdown to pdf in commandline?

I have found howtos where people suggest to use `pandoc`, but the required packages need gigabytes of dependencies:

```
apt-get install pandoc texlive-latex-base texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-extra-utils texlive-latex-extra
```

is there some minimal tool that can convert simple markdown to pdf in commandline, that does not require tons of dependencies?

I am using Debian 10.

Comment: I'd probably try to pipe the ouput of markdown to html2ps ( http://web.mit.edu/outland/share/lib/html2ps/html2ps.html ) then pipe the output to cups-pdf. (could possibly need some character encoding conversion in between doable via iconv)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the methods presented here still use pandoc in some kind of way, as the gigabytes of downloads mentioned in the question come from the LaTeX (`texlive-*`) packages in the given `apt-get` command – none of these are required. The `pandoc` package itself has a download size of ~17MB, which may or may not be acceptable for your use-case.

If you really, *really* don't want to use pandoc, then you could use [lunamark](https://github.com/jgm/lunamark) in its place. It's similar to pandoc (both tools share the same author) but lunamark is written in Lua, a very small and lean language with a small footprint. There is no Debian package available though, you'd have to build it yourself. But, as stated before, the main issue is PDF creation: all good PDF libraries must do font handling, which usually requires heavy libraries to be available.

I'm not aware of any tool that would go *directly* from Markdown to PDF, the usual way is to go to an intermediary format first. The choice of that format determines your options.

1. **groff**: GNU troff is an implementation of the troff text formatter. It's at the base of tools like `man`, is very fast, and can also produce nice looking PDF output. You'll need the `groff` and `ghostscript` packages, then call pandoc with

   ```
   pandoc --pdf-engine=pdfroff --output=out.pdf ...
   ```

   This is probably the solution that requires the fewest and smallest additional packages. Make sure though that `apt-get` won't install any unnecessary packages:

   ```
   apt-get install pandoc groff ghostscript --no-install-recommends
   ```

   On a freshly setup system this gives you

   ```
   Need to get 38.3 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 194 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   ```
2. **HTML**: There are multiple HTML-to-PDF converters, and pandoc can use two (with current versions three) of these engines to go handle the conversion from Markdown to PDF. You'll have the choice between `weasyprint`, which is written in Python, and `wkhtmltopdf`, which is built on top of the webkit HTML engine that was used in Chromium. Install either of these and then use

   ```
    pandoc --pdf-engine=weasyprint
   ```

   or

   ```
    pandoc --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf
   ```

   Especially `wkhtmltopdf` may be a good choice if you already have many graphic and font package installed anyway. E.g., on a system that has the LXDE desktop environment installed, you'd see:

   ```
   % apt-get install pandoc wkhtmltopdf --no-install-recommends
   ... [omitted] ...
   Need to get 16.4 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 122 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   ```

   However, the impact would be much more substantial on a completely fresh system:

   ```
   Need to get 91.1 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 530 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   ```
3. **LaTeX** with Docker: This method is really using LaTeX again, but instead of installing it on our system, we use a Docker image that contains pandoc and only the bare minimum of LaTeX packages, making it comparatively small. You'll need the `docker.io` package, then run this lengthy command:

   ```bash
   docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/data -u $(id -u):$(id -g) pandoc/latex --output=out.pdf ...
   ```

   The advantage of this is that you'll be using the latest pandoc and LaTeX versions, and it gives the nicest looking PDF (IMHO). However, the Docker image is still ~200MB in size, and Docker itself is also large (>90MB download size).
4. **LibreOffice**: This method only makes sense if you already have LibreOffice installed, as it is a very large dependency. In that case, pandoc can be used to convert to `odt` or `docx`, which then can be converted to PDF with

   ```
    lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf intermediary.odt
   ```

I hope one of these suits your needs.

Comment: I think the idea of the original user was to _get rid of_ `pandoc`.

Comment: @Kusalananda My understanding is that the many large `texlive-*` packages are a problem. The `pandoc` package is a mere `17MB` in download size.

Comment: So, is there a way to install `pandoc` on Debian 10 without the unnecessary dependencies? Your alternatives seem to be various different ways of invoking `pandoc`, but you don't mention how to install `pandoc` (or an alternative to it) in a way that does not pull in "gigabytes of dependencies", which is the main point of the question. In fact, some alternatives seems to not only require `pandoc` but also other very heavy pieces of software.

Comment: The reason why I include so many heavy pieces of software is that many of those are often already installed on a typical desktop machine. I agree that these are unsuitable when coming from a bare-bones system: the main packages are quite small, but the dependencies are heavy; hence the wording "good choice if you have the dependencies installed anyway".

Answer (score 1):

Going with the Markdown -> HTML -> PDF route, with [HTML to PDF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711059/315718) answered by @tarleb or [HTML to PDF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710817/convert-markdown-to-pdf-in-commandline#comment1346351_710817) answered by @MC68020

### [discount](https://www.pell.portland.or.us/%7Eorc/Code/markdown/)

This [(debian package)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/discount) is made in C and I would consider it to be the least dependent of the options I have seen.

- For a file named "filename.md"
- `markdown filename.md` to output HTML (or `makepage filename.md` for fully formed XHTML) to `stdout`
- The `stdout` may be diverted to a file if required, using `>` or `>>`
- I got this from Okular, which you can easily use in case you have the option for a GUI and Qt dependencies, but will easily get to ~200MB if you don't have them already.

Note: One might be able to go further and checkout how to create a PDF same as what Okular uses to export.